# How to draw a pin on a map in iOS 6 using Apple Maps?

Tags: ios, dictionary

How to draw a pin on map in iOS 6?

We are using the mapkit framework in iOS 5.

Comment: You can still use MapKit. Are you seeing any particular problems drawing pins?

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly the same in iOS 5 and 6.  If you need an example, the [MapCallouts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html) project from Apple will walk you through it.

Answer (score 1):

It works (almost) **exactly** as in iOS 5. In iOS 6, MapKit has of course been updated, but the framework works the same way. The major change is the map provider, being changed from Google to Apple. This doesn't change the way you use the `MKMapKit` **framework** at all.